# What is the difference of map vs path?

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, requirejs

What is the difference between map vs path when building a theme / module?

Which are the restrictions?

```js
var config = {

 map: {
    '*': {
        'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
        'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min'
    }
  },
  paths: {            
      'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
      'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min'
  }
};
```

Comment: Maybe this helps https://www.tutorialspoint.com/requirejs/requirejs_configuration.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both does the same thing, while a map has an additional advantage to create an alias for entire Magento or a specific module.

Path does not have that advantage. It will consider for the entire Magento.

In your code,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
            'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min'
        },
        'MyVendor_MyModule': {
            'jqueryjs': 'MyVendor_MyModule/js/jquery',
        }
    },
    paths: {            
        'jqueryjs': 'India_Newtheme/js/jquery',
        'bootstrapmin': 'India_Newtheme/js/vendor/bootstrap.min'
    }
};
```

If you are defining something in `"*"` within map, it will consider for entire Magento, but if the same thing you define within some module name, in our case `MyVendor_MyModule` whenever the same alias `jquery` will be called within your module js file, it will call `MyVendor_MyModule/js/jquery` instead of `India_Newtheme/js/jquery`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`map` can be scoped to specific modules whereas `paths` cannot be. Also, `map` resolves only full module names, whereas `paths` can be used for URLs, partial directory paths, etc.

More information can be found in the **new DevDocs documentation** for RequireJS config: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs.html

Also, for more in-depth usage examples: refer to https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths for `paths` and https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map for `map`